# Adding url to Google Static Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google's Static Maps API to add a map image to our Client's site. I want this to click through to the main Google Maps site. How do I find out the URL to use for this link?

I've looked through [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), but it does not seem to be mentioned and none of the example maps have links on.

My static map image is:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=14&size=560x370&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Csize:small%7C51.466848,-0.1428261&sensor=false" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://maps.google.com/maps and add the lat&lng as q-parameter

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=51.466848,-0.1428261